# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'documentSnapshot.exists')

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have a component `ShowReportCount` which throws an error when I logout with `auth().signOut();` It presents me with the following error:

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating
> 'documentSnapshot.exists')

`console.log('UID:', user.uid)` returns:

```
**UID:** lzDbqczG5yXaMJRzHZO3VQEOD0n2
```

`console.log('dbUser:', dbUser)` returns:

```
**dbUser:** {"_documentPath": {"_parts": ["users", "lzDbqczG5yXaMJRzHZO3VQEOD0n2"]}, "_firestore": {"_app": {"_automaticDataCollectionEnabled": true, "_deleteApp": [Function bound deleteApp], "_deleted": false, "_initialized": true, "_name": "[DEFAULT]", "_nativeInitialized": true, "_options": [Object]}, "_config": {"ModuleClass": [Function FirebaseFirestoreModule], "hasCustomUrlOrRegionSupport": false, "hasMultiAppSupport": true, "namespace": "firestore", "nativeEvents": [Array], "nativeModuleName": [Array], "statics": [Object], "version": "10.5.1"}, "_customUrlOrRegion": undefined, "_nativeModule": {"RNFBFirestoreCollectionModule": true, "RNFBFirestoreDocumentModule": true, "RNFBFirestoreModule": true, "RNFBFirestoreTransactionModule": true, "clearPersistence": [Function anonymous], "collectionGet": [Function anonymous], "collectionOffSnapshot": [Function anonymous], "collectionOnSnapshot": [Function anonymous], "disableNetwork": [Function anonymous], "documentBatch": [Function anonymous], "documentDelete": [Function anonymous], "documentGet": [Function anonymous], "documentOffSnapshot": [Function anonymous], "documentOnSnapshot": [Function anonymous], "documentSet": [Function anonymous], "documentUpdate": [Function anonymous], "enableNetwork": [Function anonymous], "getConstants": [Function anonymous], "setLogLevel": [Function anonymous], "settings": [Function anonymous], "terminate": [Function anonymous], "transactionApplyBuffer": [Function anonymous], "transactionBegin": [Function anonymous], "transactionDispose": [Function anonymous], "transactionGetDocument": [Function anonymous], "waitForPendingWrites": [Function anonymous]}, "_referencePath": {"_parts": [Array]}, "_transactionHandler": {"_firestore": [Circular], "_pending": [Object]}}}
```

Can anyone provide me with a solution to this issue?

**ShowReportCount.js**

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

import styles from './ShowReportCount.styles';
import { UserContext } from '../../../context/UserContext';

const db = firestore();

export default function ShowReportCount(type) {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    const [user, setUser] = useContext(UserContext);

    console.log('UID:', user.uid);
    const dbUser = db.collection('users').doc(user.uid);
    console.log('dbUser:', dbUser);

    dbUser.onSnapshot(
        {
            includeMetadataChanges: true,
        },
        (documentSnapshot) => {
            if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
                if (type.type === 'exercise') {
                    setCount(documentSnapshot.data().exerciseCount);
                    return;
                }

                if (type.type === 'workout') {
                    setCount(documentSnapshot.data().workoutCount);
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                console.log("error: document doesn't exist");
            }
        }
    );

    return (
        <View>
            <Text style={styles.statCardNumber}>{count.toString()}</Text>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs if there's an error happening on the `snapshot`. Make sure that the `user` has the authenticated object on it. To catch what error is happening on your snapshot, supply an error handler as a second param to `onSnapshot`. See sample code below:

```
    dbUser.onSnapshot(
        {
            includeMetadataChanges: true,
        },
        (documentSnapshot) => {
            if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
                if (type.type === 'exercise') {
                    setCount(documentSnapshot.data().exerciseCount);
                    return;
                }

                if (type.type === 'workout') {
                    setCount(documentSnapshot.data().workoutCount);
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                console.log("error: document doesn't exist");
            }
        }, (error) => {
           // Catch errors from `onSnapshot`.
           console.log(error);
    });
```

---

For more information, checkout [Handle listen errors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#handle_listen_errors).

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! It makes sense now, I wasn't handling my error so it crashed. The log that I am presented with is:

[Error: [firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.] 

Do you have any idea how to fix this? I think it has something to do with my rules in the Firestore DB. I currently have set:

rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
match /{document=**} {
allow read, write: if request.auth != null
 }
  }
} - should the user have this permission?

Comment: That just means that the caller should be signed in or authenticated to be able to execute the query. It should be better to post another question regarding your Firestore Security Rules to be able to help you further.